The measure of what sets is uniquely determined by _finite_ additivity (and translation invariance and normalisation)?
I am very familiar with measure theory but am currently wondering about how far finitary methods can take you.
Two aspects have to be differentiated: the unique determination and the calculation of areas / volumes.
Clearly there is no finitary method to calculate the area of the circle (as $\pi$ is transcendental).
However, the area of the circle is uniquely determined as soon as one requires translation invariance, finite additivity and the normalization of the area of the unit square (this is the result of the method of Exhaustion which does not require any infinitary methods but proof by contradiction).
I know that Dehn's work on Hilbert's third Problem shows that (in dimension 3 and higher) one can not obtain certain polytopes (such as pyramids) by cutting and gluing cubes finitely many times. This surprising fact again gives a strong restriction on how far finitary methods can lead for the calculation of volume.
There seems to be some implications for the theory of valuations on convex bodies. I am only vaguely familiar with this theory but would also be very interested in some exposition on the relations to measure theory.
The Jordan measure seems to take the idea of the method of exhaustion to its completion.
Let $[0,1]^d \in \mathfrak{F} \subset \mathfrak{P}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be any ring of sets (in particular closed under finite unions) that is also closed under translation.
Lets say that $\mathfrak{F}$ is nice if
there is exactly one finitely additive and translation invariant set function $\mu$ with $\mu([0,1]^d) = 1$.
Now my question: Is the system of Jordan measurable sets the largest nice system?
